# How can I store user inputs from a html page to mongodb?

Tags: html, mongodb

**How can I store user inputs from an HTML page to MongoDB?**

Comment: Little more explanation will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing user inputs from an HTML page to Mongodb can be done in many ways.

Simplest Service Oriented Architecture approach

> HTML --> AJAX XMLHttpRequest --> Restful service --> MongoDB 
>   Use JSON Data type

There are number of tutorials available in the net, I have posted some of them

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=az5QHkwxRk8

http://www.tweetegy.com/2011/12/connecting-a-html5-application-to-a-mongodb-instance-via-mongolab-rest-api/

https://dzone.com/articles/modern-web-apps-using-jax-rs